# Как сделать валидацию того что введено в input?

Tags: javascript, input, валидация

В HTML есть несколько тегов `input` (name, surname, age и тд.).

Задача с помощью JS определить, если в `name` символы кроме букв (цифры, например). Если да то выделить этот `input` красным.

И соответственно если в `age` есть буквы, то тоже выделить поле красным.

Я перебрал массив с содержимым `name & surname` и организовал цикл:

```
var input_a = document.getElementsByClassName('name_surname'))
```

но у меня видимо в условии что то неправильно.

Можете подсказать как выглядит условие по нахождению цифр в `input`, и как выделить этот `input` красным?

Comment: нужны регулярные выражения которые будут проверять находится ли у тебя там цифры или нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Можете подсказать как выглядит условие по нахождению цифр в `input` и
> как выделить его красным?

Пример, от которого Вы можете оттолкнуться:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input")
const button = document.querySelector("button")

const handleInput = () => {
  input.style.background = ""
}

const handleClick = () => {
  handleInput()
  const value = input.value.trim()
  if (!/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(value)) {
    input.style.background = "red"
  } else {
    console.log("Все ОК, имя содержит только буквы латинского алфавита")
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", handleClick)

// следует ограничить частоту вызовов
// добавив условие при котором вызов
// handleInput будет обрабатываться
input.addEventListener("input", handleInput)
```

```html
<input name="name" />
<button>Валидировать</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/

`/^[a-zа-яё ]+$/i` — Начало строки `^`, конец строки `$`, только буквы в интервале от [a-z, а-я или пробел], `+` один или много совпадений. Флажок `i` - insensitive, чтобы учитывать и маленькие, и большие буквы.

`/^\d+$/` — только цифры (digit)

```js
document.getElementById("name").addEventListener("input", function() {
  this.style.borderColor = /^[a-zа-яё ]+$/i.test( this.value.trim() ) ? "" : "red";
});

document.getElementById("age").addEventListener("input", function() {
  this.style.borderColor = /^\d+$/.test( this.value.trim() ) ? "" : "red";
});
```

```css
input { border: 2px solid #999; outline: none; }
```

```html
<input id="age" placeholder="Возраст">
<input id="name" placeholder="Имя">
```